# Поместить цифру в квадрат

Tags: html, css, css3, span

Не получается поместить цифру 5, как на рисунке в квадрат. Пробовала с помощью `span`, но что-то не так, в чём проблема?

```css
.form-title-little {
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.form-title-little span {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #7925ec;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-title-little">
  Осталось всего <span>5</span> квартир!
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вместо `width` & `height` — `padding` для `span`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.form-title-little {
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.form-title-little span {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 10px 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0px;
  border: 1px solid #7925ec;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-title-little">
  Осталось всего <span>5</span> квартир!
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<span>` - *inline* элемент и для того, чтоб ему установить ширину и высоту нужно его сделать *inline-block*

```css
.form-title-little {
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

.form-title-little span {
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  border: 1px solid #7925ec;
  border-radius: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 28px;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-title-little">
  Осталось всего <span>5</span> квартир!
</div>
```